# Header Files Mystery

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Why do we use Quotation Marks ("...") for custom build classes and braces for built in classes(`<...>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, from what I've heard, angle brackets (`<`'s) are used to denote that the header was provided with the compiler, OR that the compiler has been told about a directory in which the header file can be found (`-I`). Quotes (`"`'s) are usually used for header files within the source tree. But like others have mentioned, it's not a requirement.

Comment: Even if the header is within the source tree, you still have to tell the compiler how to find it.  `-I.` is not the default.

Comment: What? I never said -I was the default ... I said < is for something like <string>, or if you specify a path with -I

Answer (score 5):

It's to denote that the header isn't system-wide.

This is a convention, not a requirement.

By the way, those aren't inverted commas, they're quotation marks.  There is a difference in the field of typography.

Comment: <> aren't braces either ... :p

Comment: typographically speaking, they're not true quotation marks either. Quotation marks look like “this”, not "this". :)

Answer (score 2):

At least for C, it makes no difference nowadays. The ISO standard states that the location of the files is implementation defined in both cases.

The usual way is to use `<>` for system headers (things under `/usr/include` for example) and `""` for your own headers, but it's not required.

The relevant bits of [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) are from 6.10.2, "Source file inclusion", quoted below.

---

A preprocessing directive of the form

```
# include <h-char-sequence> new-line
```

searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by
the specified sequence between the `<` and `>` delimiters, and causes the replacement of that
directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header
identified is implementation-defined.

A preprocessing directive of the form

```
# include "q-char-sequence" new-line
```

causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified
by the specified sequence between the `"` delimiters. The named source file is searched
for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search
fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read

```
# include <h-char-sequence> new-line
```

with the identical contained sequence (including `>` characters, if any) from the original
directive.

Comment: quote and link the standard for bonus points :D

Comment: Why bother, Matt? It's quoted in probably every other dup of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162030/difference-between-angle-bracket-and-double-quotes-while-including-header/3162067#3162067 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename/77092#77092