# C language, How to include a file from "XXX.h" to <XXX.h>", maybe using Makefile?

Tags: c, header, include, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

I just got involved into a project.

When I were tracing the project code, I found that

some people can include a header file by this way:

include < XXX.h >

XXX.h is a header file that is not in system libraries and made by our own programmers...

My question is how to use '<' and '>' instead of double " ?

and how to include headers in other directories by this way?

for example:

headers/header_a.h
headers/header_b.h

I can use include < header_a.h > and < header_b.h >...

should I use Makefile to implement this? thanks..

Comment: And the answer is, you don't.  You use <> for system includes and "" for your files because that is how they are intended to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file in double-quotes is referenced relative to the current directory:

```
#include "../file.h" // file from parent directory
```

You'd generally use this for your own headers.

A file in angle-brackets is referenced relative to the paths specified to the compiler:

```
#include <sys/bits.h> // file under, e.g.,  /usr/include
#include <thirdpartytools/somelib.h> // file under /path/to/third/party/includes
```

You'd generally use this for system or perhaps third-party headers, assuming the compiler is invoked with something like

```
gcc -I/usr/include -I/path/to/third/party/includes ...
```

Comment: TO add the current directory, use gcc -I. ...

Answer (score 0):

The <> usually denotes System headers and the "" usually denote header files in the current directory (usually your header files).  Source/Reference here for more info:
[Difference between angle bracket < > and double quotes " " while including header files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162030/difference-between-angle-bracket-and-double-quotes-while-including-heade)