# What does "#include <iostream>" do?

Tags: c++

As I started learning basic C++, I've always used the headings

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

I want to question what is the point of iostream. Is it required every time as a heading?

Comment: No, unless you want to get/write something from/to the stream.

Comment: What exactly is the stream?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In order to read or write to the [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin))/[output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) streams, you need to include it.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That program will not compile unless you add `#include <iostream>`

The second line isn't necessary:

```
using namespace std;
```

That does tell the compiler that symbol names defined in the `std` namespace are to be brought into your program's scope, so you can omit the namespace qualifier, and write for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice you no longer need to refer to the output stream with the fully qualified name `std::cout` and can use the shorter name `cout`.

I personally don't like bringing in all symbols in the namespace of a header file... I'll individually select the symbols I want to be shorter... so I would do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But that is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 14):

That is a [C++ standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_standard_library) header file for [input output streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iostream#Input.2Foutput_streams). It includes functionality to read and write from streams. You only need to include it if you wish to use streams.

Comment: You have not answered the question at all

Comment: @Pynchia What more would you expect in the answer? The accepted answer is quite a bit longer, but the posted code is including the C++ standard library header file for input output streams. Which is literally how the accepted answer starts. `#include <cstdio> int main() { puts("Hello, World!"); }` is still valid C++. But doesn't use the C++ standard library header file.

Answer (score 12):

`#` indicates that the following line is a preprocessor directive and should be processed by the preprocessor before compilation by the compiler.

So, `#include` is a preprocessor directive that tells the preprocessor to include header files in the program.

`< >` indicate the start and end of the file name to be included.

`iostream` is a header file that contains functions for input/output operations (`cin` and `cout`).

Now to sum it up C++ to English translation of the command, `#include <iostream>` is:

Dear preprocessor, please include all the contents of the header file `iostream` at the very beginning of this program before compiler starts the actual compilation of the code.

Comment: Files specified by `#include` are transcluded at the point of the `#include`, not the start of the file

Comment: to be super verbose.. also note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162030/difference-between-angle-bracket-and-double-quotes-while-including-heade

Answer (score 0):

#include where as is the including the functionsfor the input AND output (cin and cout) operations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i think of header files:
You want to make mac and cheese. You have two options, either:
A) Make the entire thing from scratch
B) Make it from a box of kraft mac and cheese.

The box is kind of like a header file.  I know I want to use this set of ingredients. But cheese powder is something most people don't have on hand in their kitchen.  So the box does the work for you.

Same thing with , or input/output stream.  It is this box of stuff that you just bring into your code.  You are basically saying "I want to be able to write things into and get things out of my code" when you use it.

You could absolutely build that functionality into your code without  but it would take a lot of extra work.  Just like you can make mac and cheese from scratch, you can even make the noodles.  But it is so easy to buy the box and just import it into your kitchen.  The work is already done for you, taking a several hours long task and turning it into a short one.