# Error when running CLion C++ Sample Program

Tags: c++, clion

I just downloaded CLion, together with minGW, and created a project. After a lot of hazzle I managed to get the button for running the sample Hello World program. However, when I try to run the program it says that it compiles to 50% before giving me this error log: https://justpaste.it/wm14

It is extremely long, about 450 lines. And I have no idea why I get this error... Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

The first few lines of the errors are as follows. There is a repeating pattern similar to this in the list of errors that begins `In file included from` followed by a list of errors such as `has not been declared using` or `is not a member of 'std'` or `does not name a type`:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:208:0,
from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\cwchar:44,
from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\ios:38,
from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\ostream:38,
from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\iostream:39,
from C:\Users\Ole\Documents\programming\c++\testing\main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_ino_t' does not name a type
struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_mode_t' does not name a type
struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
^
```

Here is the code:

```
#include "iostream"

int main () {
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have managed to isolate the problem to the include statement. If I remove the include (and the cout), it builds fine, but if I add the include (and not the cout) it gives me the same error.

**Update**

I managed to solve this by simply deleting `minGW` and installing `cygwin`.

Comment: Please add your code to your question.

Comment: I have now added the code.

Comment: I even managed to narrow down the problem :D

Comment: See what happens if you change the quotes on the `include` directive to angle brackets instead. [Difference between angle bracket < > and double quotes “ ” while including header files in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162030/difference-between-angle-bracket-and-double-quotes-while-including-heade) as well as  [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) I suspect a possible include search path problem.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, but it's solved now at least

Comment: @InzaneNova, what did you change to make it work?

Comment: Your error log is blocked on my proxy at work. Thats why you should include all relevant information to the question and only provide bonus information as external link

Comment: @RichardChambers I added the info at the end of the question, but I deleted minGW and used cygwin instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
#include <iostream>
```

instead of

```
#include "iostream"
```

- like Richard C suggested I'd also guess it's a search path problem.