# #include <QDatetime> cause fatal error: QDatetime: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

I was trying to compile gpsd package with arm-Linux-gnueabi-c++,
here is line:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-c++ -o qt-gpsutils.os -c -Os -Wextra -Wall -Wno- uninitialized
-Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations 
-Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -pthread -Wmissing-declarations -O2 -pthread
-fPIC -DUSE_QT -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork
-I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore gpsutils.c

gpsutils.c:26:21: fatal error: QDateTime: No such file or directory
#include <QDateTime>

compilation terminated.
scons: *** [qt-gpsutils.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I checked my PC directory /usr/include/qt4/QtCore, it has QDatetime file, what is the problem.

Comment: tried with  #include "QDateTime.h" , same problem.

Comment: According to [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html), `#include <QDateTime>` is correct. Note the capital `T` in `Time`.

Comment: Sorry, after I voted to close I noticed that the error message refers to `QDateTime`, which is the correct spelling. But your title and the body of the question refer to `QDatetime`, which is incorrect. Please double-check the spelling and update the question to be consistent.

Comment: @pingul It is [conventional, and perhaps advantageous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3162067/2757035), to use angled brackets when `#include`ing library headers. But more to the point, a quick glance at various API docs indicates that Qt does not use `.h` extensions. So, your suggestion is misguided.

Comment: Are you cross compiling? And trying to include non-sysroot headers?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me commenting out a line in the generated .pro did the trick.
I created a test project and there the line

```
CONFIG -= qt
```

removed all qt modules i added before (e.g. by writing QT += core).
After commenting this line my problems went away. You could also write

```
CONFIG += qt
```

that would be the normal configuration line for QT projects i think.

**Edit:**
Your output suggests that this config variable is already set and QTCore is added to the libraries that are linked. I use QT 5.10 and there the compilation flags/defines are named differently, so i am not shure what happened in your case.