# no operators "<<" match these operands

Tags: c++, include

I get the error:
no operators ">>" match these operands.
and
string is not a member of std.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    std::string forName;
    std::cout << "Write your name below please:/n";
    std::cin >> forName;
    std::cout << forName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're trying to include your own header files, `include` statements in C++ should use angular brackets:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdafx.h>
```

Also, if you're writing C++: I suggest that you use `<string>` instead of `<string.h>`, because the latter is a C header (not C++) and is deprecated in C++. If not then ignore this bit :)

Comment: 'code'
'#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
 std::string forName;
 std::cout << "Write your name below please:/n";
 std::cin >> forName;
 std::cout << forName;
}'

Comment: What development environment/compiler are you using?

Comment: Try putting `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top of the code, above all the other `include` statements. Also notice the quotation marks instead of the angular brackets -- originally thought stdafx.h was a library but realized that it's generated by VS. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

Everything included above `#include "stdafx.h"` is ignored by Visual Studio. More information on why this is can be found here:  [What's the use for "stdafx.h" in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726155/whats-the-use-for-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio)

So

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Must be

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string.h"
```

After that you can optimize the searching for the include files by surrounding headers with the appropriate `<>` or `""`. Selecting which to use is covered here: [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

In addition, string.h is a C header for C string utilities. It does not include the class `string`. For that you need

```
#include <string>
```

If you do want the C string utilities, it is recommended you use the C++ version

```
#include <cstring>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the quotation marks to angle brackets.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdafx.h>
```

See this question for more information about the difference between the two: [Difference between angle bracket < > and double quotes " " while including header files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162030/difference-between-angle-bracket-and-double-quotes-while-including-heade)

Comment: Wrong.  Should be `#include <string>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own header file then include like this:

```
#include "yourheader.h"
```

But if you are using standard header file then you have to include like this:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must replace `#include "filename"` with `#include <filename>` 

For `#include "filename"` the preprocessor searches in the same directory as the file containing the directive. This method is normally used to include programmer-defined header files.

For `#include <filename>` the preprocessor searches in an implementation dependent manner, normally in search directories pre-designated by the compiler/IDE. This method is normally used to include standard library header files.

Answer (score -1):

The string.h library is actually deprecated within C++.  Try using string instead, or if you need functionality that is from string.h (strcpy, strlen), try using cstring.

Comment: This sounds a little bit unprecise. Use `#include <cstring>` for C string functions (e.g. `strcpy()`). Use `#include <string>` for C++ string classes (e.g. `std::string`). Due to the existance of keyword `using`, your wording _could_ be misunderstood.