# Swift package manager unable to compile ncurses installed through Homebrew

Tags: swift, ncurses, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to use ncurses in a library using Swift Package Manager and I'd like to use a specific version of ncurses, not the one included in OS X.
To do so I installed a more recent version (6.1) using Homebrew.
This is how my `Package.swift` looks like:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "NcursesExample",
    products: [
        .executable(name: "NcursesExample", targets: ["NcursesExample"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .systemLibrary(name: "Cncurses"),
        .target(name: "NcursesExample", dependencies: ["Cncurses"]),
    ]
)
```

Under the Sources directory I have a subdirectory for Cncurses containing a `module.modulemap` and `shim.h` files:

**module.modulemap**

```
module Cncurses {
  header "shim.h"
  link "ncurses"
  export *
}
```

**shim.h**

```
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/ncurses.h"
```

However, when compiling I get several errors complaining about conflicting types, apparently because ncurses is also provided by the macOS SDK:

```
shim.h:1:10: note: in file included from shim.h:1:
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/ncurses.h"
         ^
/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/ncurses.h:60:10: error: 'ncursesw/ncurses_dll.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#include <ncursesw/ncurses_dll.h>
         ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "shim.h"
        ^
shim.h:1:10: note: in file included from shim.h:1:
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/ncurses.h"
         ^
/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/ncurses.h:674:45: error: conflicting types for 'keyname'
extern NCURSES_EXPORT(NCURSES_CONST char *) keyname (int);              /* implemented */
                                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/curses.h:598:45: note: previous declaration is here
extern NCURSES_EXPORT(NCURSES_CONST char *) keyname (int);              /* implemented */

...
```

I'm trying to compile the package using:

`swift build -Xcc -I/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/ -Xlinker -L/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/lib`

I also went down the route of specifying the `pkgConfig` on the package definition, with the same result. Can someone help?

FYI It's worth mentioning that upon ncurses installation through Homebrew I get the following warning as ncurses is already provided by OS X:

```
ncurses is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have ncurses first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find ncurses you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ncurses/include"

For pkg-config to find ncurses you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Pkgconfig for ncurses looks like this

```
# pkg-config file generated by gen-pkgconfig
# vile:makemode

prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include/ncursesw
abi_version=6
major_version=6
version=6.1.20180127

Name: ncursesw
Description: ncurses 6.1 library
Version: ${version}
URL: https://invisible-island.net/ncurses
Requires.private:
Libs:  -L${libdir} -lncursesw
Libs.private:
Cflags:  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -I/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include -I${includedir}
```

Comment: What is in your `/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig` file? You likely need other compiler flags to be passed in as well.

Comment: Edited my question to include the contents of the pkgconfig.

Comment: I'm curious, could this be related to the use of ncurses vs ncursesw?

Comment: That is likely the issue. Does it work if you add the `Cflags` and `Libs` flags to your `swift build` or modulemap's link command?

Comment: No, doesn't work even with the Cflags/Libs specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem**

The main problem are conflicts of the header files, since ncurses is also supplied in /Applications/Xcode.app/.../MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include.

A common pure C solution in such situations is to just specify the custom include and lib directories with -I repective -L and it would work, see my answer regarding C ncurses here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56623033/2331445

This approach does not seem to work with the Swift package manager. But that doesn't mean it's not possible with a little effort.

**Possible Solution**

We need to make sure that the ncurses header files provided by the macOS SDK are ignored. We can do this by specifying the -Xcc -D__NCURSES_H parameter for the swift build command.

This works because in the header file, there is this typical:

```
#ifndef __NCURSES_H
#define __NCURSES_H
...
#endif
```

The problem, of course, is that our custom installation of ncurses using Brew is also affected. But we can work around it:

- copy the new ncurses header files into our Sources/Cncurses directory
- replace __NCURSES_H through something different, e.g. __CNCURSES_H (note leading 'C')
- then make sure that all further nested includes are first searched in our local include directory by replace the angle brackets of the includes with quotes, so e.g. instead of `#include <ncursesw/unctrl.h>` the form '#include "ncursesw/unctrl.h"' is used

This can actually be done with the following command line commands:

```
cd Sources/Cncurses
cp -r /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include include
find . -name '*.h' -exec sed -i ''  's/__NCURSES_H/__CNCURSES_H/g' {} \;
find . -name '*.h' -exec sed -i '' -E -e "s/<(.*(`find . -name '*.h' -exec basename {} \; |  paste -sd "|" -`))>/\"\1\"/g"  {} \;
```

The last statement may require some explanation. With the help of an echo command, you can look at the generated sed expression, i.e. if you execute

```
echo "s/<(.*(`find . -name '*.h' -exec basename {} \; |  paste -sd "|" -`))>/\"\1\"/g"
```

you get the following output:

```
s/<(.*(termcap.h|form.h|term.h|panel.h|ncurses.h|termcap.h|cursesp.h|cursesf.h|etip.h|form.h|cursesw.h|nc_tparm.h|unctrl.h|cursesapp.h|term.h|cursslk.h|panel.h|ncurses.h|tic.h|eti.h|ncurses_dll.h|term_entry.h|menu.h|cursesm.h|curses.h|curses.h|cncurses.h))>/"\1"/g
```

As you can see, it searches and replaces only local available include files.

**Test**

For a test we need a simple ncurses example program. It should be built and we should make sure that the correct version of the library is used.

*module.modulemap*

My header file is called cncurses.h. The module.modulemap looks like this:

```
module cncurses [system] 
{
    umbrella header "cncurses.h"
    link "ncurses"
    export *
}
```

*cncurses.h*

cncurses.h is a one-liner, it imports our copied and customized ncurses.h file from our local include folder:

```
#include "include/ncurses.h"
```

*main.swift*

In the NcursesExample folder we have main.swift where we have a simple cncurses swift app:

```
import cncurses

initscr()
curs_set(0) 
move(5, 10)
addstr("NCURSES")
move(10, 10)
addstr("Hello World!")
refresh() 

select(0, nil, nil, nil, nil)
```

*Package.swift*

Please note here the `pkgConfig: "ncurses"` in the systemLibrary targets:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "NcursesExample",
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .systemLibrary(name: "cncurses", pkgConfig: "ncurses"),
        .target(name: "NcursesExample", dependencies: ["cncurses"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "NcursesExampleTests",
            dependencies: ["NcursesExample"]),

    ]
)
```

**Build**

For pkg-config to do its job properly, we must first call the following:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Finally we initiate the build with:

```
swift build -Xcc -D__NCURSES_H
```

So first we should test if the correct ncurses lib was used. We can do that with:

```
otool -L .build/x86_64-apple-macosx/debug/NcursesExample
```

Among other lines, the output contains this:

```
/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/libncursesw.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
```

which looks promising.

Finally calling the binary:

[image: ncurses demo]

**Xcode Project**

If you want to generate a Xcode project, use the following command:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

Then load the project in Xcode and

- select the project node
- in Build settings enter Preprocessor in the search field in the upper right
- under Apple Clang - Preprocessing / Preprocess Macros add __NCURSES_H=1 for Debug and Release

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Out of curiosity why isn't the -I flag working when Swift Package Manager allows passing those flags to the C compiler (is it just a bug)?
Also can you advise on how to set up Xcode in order to compile the package, instead of having to go through the command line?

Comment: I've added Xcode project generation to the answer. Regarding -I flag I'm note sure, it seems it's not supported, perhaps because some default packages are loaded? Anyway if you want to dig deeper: with `swift build --verbose ...` one can see the swiftc command line...

Comment: Wow, this seems somewhat overkill (in some aspects), but I'll try using this approach with my PoC project (from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566910/i-cant-import-macports-opt-local-include-ncurses-h-into-my-swift-project-it/56769024 ). 

I'm not 100% sure about how to apply some specifics to my project, but in case I have some doubts I'll ask @StephanSchlecht who seems to know things :) 
So eager to try it!!. I want my blink effect back, my 16 colors and all my expected standard fancy effects now !!

Comment: I historically dislike Brew and am a fan of MacPorts, so I'm trying to adapt your solution to my MacPorts installation... I managed to copy my ncurses.h and ncurses_dll.h (/opt/local/include/ncurses.h /opt/local/include/ncurses_dll.h) into some Source/cncurses folder I created by hand, but from there I get somewhat lost. with some unknown files to me: I have no idea about the required path to deploy them... module.modulemap? cncurses.h ? Never had to deal with this way of using swift compiler, so I'm 100% newbie and I can't really follow you... Still trying to figure out the rest of the stuff

Comment: @StephanSchlecht I can get it to compile on the command line, but not in Xcode with the instructions you provided.

Comment: Conflicting nurses types, feels like the __NCURSES_H=1 flag ins't being applied properly maybe? Also, do I need to run script phase to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH? Thanks.

Comment: on the command line you made the call `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig"`and afterwards `swift package generate-xcodeproj`? And then you selected in Xcode on the left 'Project' and on the right `Build Settings`? Added `__NCURSES_H=1` to preprocess Macros? Then it should work. Perhaps clean project and remove `/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and try again.

Comment: Working - great! Now I just need to understand why functions such as `init_pair` aren't imported to Swift, although that's a different fight... Thanks for your help! @StephanSchlecht

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too well-versed in this subject, but it seems like you may want to look into adding a build script for this to your project. In Xcode, under the selected project, go to Build Phases > New Run Script Phase

[image]

In that script add your flags:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ncurses/include"
```

The build script should run on install. I'm not sure if you need the pkg-config flag here. Hope this helps point you somewhere in the right direction.

Comment: This didn't work. Also, I should be able to build on the command line. I had tried `swift build -Xcc -I/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/ -Xlinker -L/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/lib` before but without results.

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/ncurses.h"
```

to

```
#include <ncurses.h>
```

because you already have

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/
```

Reading the [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/ncurses.rb), you should have

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/include/ncursesw/ncurses_dll.h
```

(and some other stuff), but using a quoted-include can interfere with the search path which the `-I` option sets up (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162030/difference-between-angle-bracket-and-double-quotes-while-including-heade) for example).